# Solving a polynomial with complex coefficients

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

So I have the following : $z^6 +(2i-1)z^3 -1 -i$

I'm not sure how to tackle this. I guess that i could do this :

$(z^2)^3-i + (2i-1)z^3 -1$

we know that $i^3$=-i

then

$(z^2)^3+i^3 + (2i-1)z^3 -1$

$(z^2+i)(z^4-iz^2-1) + (2i-1)z^3 -1$

Other than that I don't know what to do... Any hints ? I guess there is a second cube I need to factor but I'm not sure

Comment: Let $w=z^3$. Solve $w^2+(2i-1)w-1-i$ and then find $z$.

Comment: Pose $Z=z^3$. You're ou're then back to a second degree polynomial.

Comment: If you want to solve then it should be an equation and so you should write $=0$.

Comment: Ok, IM going to try this approach and see what it gives. Thank you for the hints !

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**

$$(z^3)^2+(2i-1)z^3-(1+i)=0\implies z^3=\frac{(1-2i)\pm\sqrt{(2i-1)^2+4(1+i)}}{2}$$Simplify it and then find cube root...

Comment: I obtained (-8i+1)^1/2 how do I simplify this ?